# How to import data from sql server on premise to Azure SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

We need to move data in a table from on premise SQL server to Azure SQL server. I could not able to do this using import wizard. 
I am trying to accomplish this using csv.
I have imported data into a CSV file and created a SSIS package to read that data into azure SQL server.
It's continuously throwing data type errors as below.

> [Flat File Source [2]] Error: Data conversion failed. The data
>   conversion for column "Finance Charge Dollar" returned status value 2
>   and status text "The value could not be converted because of a
>   potential loss of data.".

I am getting the same error even after changing the data type. If I remove the column from import, the next column is having the same issue.

Can somebody please suggest how this can be fixed?

Thanks

Comment: Is this data that you have to import into an existing table, or can you start fresh on the Azure end, creating the new table with your import?

Comment: It is clearly data type mis match from CSV to staging table, use a derived column transformation and check if it works

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to migrate your database or tables on your database to Azure SQL Database is using [Data Migration Assistant](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53595).  You can use this tool to perform an assessment first of your database, make adjustments when required by the assessment stage, and later migrate it to Azure SQL Database.

Another easy way to migrate to Azure SQL Database is [Azure Database Migration Service](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/database-migration/).

Comment: Data Migration Assistant (DMA) is a good option provided that the destination table is empty (but I'd argue over a beer that Database Migration Service is an "easy" way to migrate).
DMA will do the migration directly without the need for a CSV file in between provided that the schema of the source and destination tables match.  If the destination table is not empty then create a specific import table, load there and then query that into the final table.